# Is it possible to create auto increment id column in mysql view?

Tags: mysql

I have created a view in MySql. But now my requirement is to create an Id column in that view which should be auto increment.

My current view is:-

```
CREATE VIEW pending_assign_report_view AS
  select cg.group_name,c.client_name, wt.work_type,p.Minor_worktype, ay.year,aev.emp_name,ep.Date_assigned_on
from employee_project ep,active_employee_view aev, project p, client_group cg, client c,work_type wt,assessment_year ay
where ep.task_status_id=1 and ep.username=aev.username and ep.project_id=p.project_id and p.Year_id=ay.Year_id
and p.Client_group_id=cg.client_group_id and p.Client_id=c.Client_id and p.Work_type_id=wt.Work_type_id
order by cg.group_name,c.client_name, aev.emp_name;
```

Now I want Id column as first column which should be auto_increment in nature. How should I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I think this question is a duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964811/row-rank-in-a-mysql-view/1964850

Comment: Short answer: No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808759/creating-a-mysql-view-with-an-auto-incrementing-id-column

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808759/creating-a-mysql-view-with-an-auto-incrementing-id-column/45963661#45963661

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate it with something like this in your SELECT:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, dummy.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, dummy;
```

Comment: Note: this will enumerate all rows in your resultset, indepent of the order of your actual query!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But when I m creating view mysql gives error:- View's select contains a variable or parameter.

Answer (score 2):

View in database is a mirror copy of our some data from our database. In real it does not exist. It have same structure as of main table

So its structure can not change

Comment: Thanks Lokesh. Can we create a function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can USE the "UIID()" function that will provide you with an unique (alphanumerical) identified.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963661/6083044

Comment: There is one major drawback with this solution: the UUIDs change every time you access the view. (BTW, don't reply to duplicates questions with the same answer, flag/vote to close the newer questions as duplicate of the oldest one.)

Answer (score -1):

select @rownum:=@rownum+1 'autoID',m.mediaThumbnailUrl , q.surveyID  from (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, media m  join question q  on m.mediaAutoID = q.backgroundImageID ;