# Querying a view with JPA returns weird results

Tags: java, jpa

this is my view data:

30.0   120.0   1500.0  16
 30.0   120.0   4000.0  16
 30.0   140.0   1500.0  16
 30.0   140.0   4000.0  16
 35.0   130.0   2750.0  18
 40.0   120.0   1500.0  16
 40.0   120.0   4000.0  16
 40.0   140.0   1500.0  16
 40.0   140.0   4000.0  16

this is my code:

```
public List<Duplicate> getData() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DXSorterPU");
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    List<Duplicate> result = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Duplicate d").getResultList();
    for (Duplicate d : result) {
        System.out.println(d.getF1()+"  " +d.getF3()+"  "+ d.getF4()+"  "+ d.getResult()) ;
    }
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    return result;
}
```

this is my data that i get with above code:

30.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 30.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 30.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 30.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 35.0  130.0  2750.0  18
 40.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 40.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 40.0  120.0  1500.0  16
 40.0  120.0  1500.0  16

Why the result is different? Please help me.

this is my Duplicate class:

```
package dxsorter;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DUPLICATE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Duplicate.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Duplicate d")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Duplicate.findByF1", query = "SELECT d FROM Duplicate d WHERE d.f1 = :f1")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Duplicate.findByF3", query = "SELECT d FROM Duplicate d WHERE d.f3 = :f3")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Duplicate.findByF4", query = "SELECT d FROM Duplicate d WHERE d.f4 = :f4")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Duplicate.findByResult", query = "SELECT d FROM Duplicate d WHERE d.result = :result")})
public class Duplicate implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "F1")
    @Id
    private BigDecimal f1;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "F3")
    private BigDecimal f3;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "F4")
    private BigDecimal f4;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "RESULT")
    private int result;

    public Duplicate() {
    }

    public BigDecimal getF1() {
        return f1;
    }

    public void setF1(BigDecimal f1) {
        this.f1 = f1;
    }

    public BigDecimal getF3() {
        return f3;
    }

    public void setF3(BigDecimal f3) {
        this.f3 = f3;
    }

    public BigDecimal getF4() {
        return f4;
    }

    public void setF4(BigDecimal f4) {
        this.f4 = f4;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public List<Duplicate> getData() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DXSorterPU");
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Duplicate> result = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Duplicate d").getResultList();
        for (Duplicate d : result) {
            System.out.println(d.getF1()+"  " +d.getF3()+"  "+ d.getF4()+"  "+ d.getResult()) ;
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be d.getF1()+"  " + d.getF2() + " " + d.getF3()+"  "+ d.getF4()?

Comment: i dont have F2 column in my view. just have 4 column (F1, F3,F4 and result).

Comment: Show your `Duplicate` declaration

Comment: JPA does not modify your query data. Something wrong with your view query!

Comment: i want to get exactly view data, because my view data is correct.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what your problem is, is it the sort order? What is different? There is a lot of code in this post and you do not show the table layout or what you've inserted. Please read [mcve]

Comment: You cant have a BigDecimal as an `@Id`. The SQL invoked is in your log, so perhaps look at it ! If a view doesn't have a unique id then you need to JPA provider that handles that situation ...

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the column that you annotated with `@Id` (F1) is not unique in your view.
Your JPA provider (for example hibernate) assumes that the value of `F1` is unique in the view.

So this is what happens when you execute the query:

Lets say that the first row that is fetched is

`30.0 120.0 1500.0 16`.

Your JPA provider associates this row with the id `30.0` (the value of the F1 column).

Lets say that the next row that is fetched is `30.0 120.0 4000.0 16`. Now, we can see that this row is different from the first one. But your JPA provider does not know that. What the provider sees is that the `id` of this row has value of `30`. Because he already fetched a row with that id (and has it in the session/cache) he believes that it is the same row. So instead of creating a new object for the second row, he puts the same object from the first row.

In order to solve this problem, you should either create a real `id` column (that will have unique values in the view) or use raw SQL queries.

**Adding an ID column to the view**

**MySQL:**
You can add a unique identifier to the view by using the `UUID()` function in mysql. That is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808759/creating-a-mysql-view-with-an-auto-incrementing-id-column).
With the UUID, your select should look like this:

```
SELECT UUID() as ID, FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4, COUNT() AS RESULT FROM APP.FACTORS GROUP BY FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4 HAVING COUNT() > 1
```

I created a simple example on rextester. You can check it out [here](https://rextester.com/QETX28769).

**Derby:**
In derby you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.
Your select should look like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as ID, FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4, COUNT() AS RESULT FROM APP.FACTORS GROUP BY FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4 HAVING COUNT() > 1
```

Comment: this is my sql to create view, how can add ID column? 
SELECT FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4, COUNT(*) AS RESULT FROM APP.FACTORS
GROUP BY FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @user9753394 I edited my answer and added the select.

Comment: error: 'UUID' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
i use derby in netbeans.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? My example is in MYSQL.
I added a mysql example to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: i use java derby database in netbeans

Comment: I am not familiar with derby, but from what I see online you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, like in this example here: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rreffuncrownumber.html.
You need to replace the `UUID() as id` with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id`

Comment: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS ID, FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4, COUNT(*) AS RESULT
FROM APP.FACTORS  
GROUP BY FACTORS.F1, FACTORS.F3, FACTORS.F4
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
/* work fine, thanks/*

Comment: I am glad it worked for you @user9753394. Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking on the checkmark next to the upvote/downvote arrows) in order to mark this answer as correct so other users will know that it works.

Comment: You can read more about accepting answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thanka to you. I Solved my problem and could understand that.